# Is it possible to use both network default and outside external in docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-network

I have two `services`:

- service A: It like a database service
- service B: It like backend service

I want, service B can request to outside World (like curl google.com), and also connect to service A using alias (or something).
Because, I don't want to public ip of service A to outside.
Is it posibile?

`docker-compose.yml` seem like that:

```
version: "3"

services:
  serviceB:
    build: ./serviceB
    networks:
      - outside
      - default
  serviceA:
    build: ./serviceA
    networks:
      - default

networks:
  outside:
    external: true
```

Answer (score 0):

Do absolutely nothing; delete all of the `networks:` declarations.  It will work as you describe.

Containers don't have "public IPs"; you can't reach a container from outside Docker space unless you have published `ports:`.  (That a container has an IP address at all is something of an implementation detail, and they are only reachable from outside Docker on native-Linux hosts, and then only from the same host; you almost never need to directly look up or use those addresses.)

With the out-of-the-box Docker setup, containers can make outbound connections just fine.  You don't need to configure anything for this.

So long as two Compose services are on the same network (including the automatic implicit `default` network) they can reach each other using their Compose service names as host names.

So if we rewrite your `docker-compose.yml` file as:

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  serviceB:
    build: ./serviceB
    ports: ['3333:3000']
  serviceA:
    build: ./serviceA
```

Then:

- Service A can't be reached from outside Docker space; service B can be reached via port 3333 on the host's IP address
- Service B can use `serviceA` as a host name to reach service A (and *vice versa*)
- Both services A and B can call the public Internet, other systems on your LAN, *etc.*

[Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) has some official documentation on how things work.

Comment: Thank for your reply, but, in serviceB, I can't reach to outside, without `network_mode:"bridge"`

Comment: That's the default (if you're not in Swarm mode), you shouldn't need to explicitly specify it.